# removing value of imploded vars with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

i have this javascript var:

```
var mylist = '1,5,3,7,9,8,44,6';
```

I need to remove the 9, so that the final value is: **1,5,3,7,8,44,6**

I usually do this server side with php (easy way). How can achieve this with javascript? A solution using jQuery would be even better.

**considerations**: it should work also if var is '99,9,96' or '9' or '99,9' or '9,98' ...etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my_list = my_list.split(',').filter(function(e) { return e != 9}).join(',');`

Later edit: to support array.filter in IE:

```
//This prototype is provided by the Mozilla foundation and
//is distributed under the MIT license.
//http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/LICENSES/mit.license

if (!Array.prototype.filter)
{
  Array.prototype.filter = function(fun)
  {
    var len = this.length;
    if (typeof fun != "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array();
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in this)
      {
        var val = this[i]; // in case fun mutates this
        if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this))
          res.push(val);
      }
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```

Comment: forgot to mention IE < 9 doesn't support array.filter so you need to add it

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```
var mylist = '1,5,3,7,9,8,44,6';

mylist = mylist.split(',').filter(function(elem, i) {
    return elem !== '9';
}).join(',');

console.log(mylist);  // = 1,5,3,7,8,44,6
```

Ref.: [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> filter():
>   Creates a new array with all elements
>   that pass the test implemented by the
>   provided function.

Comment: hi Andy, thanks for the help! matei's solution was kind of shorter.